# Generate VTT pixel flat image with coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I have a question.

I want to know if they have any options to create webVTT horizontal images with FFmpeg
like an attached image tack one pixel/two every second and create one horizontal image with coordinates.

Thank you.

[image]

```
WEBVTT
```

00:00.000 --> 00:08.000
/assets/thumbnails-01.jpg#xywh=0,0,160,90

00:09.000 --> 00:16.000
/assets/thumbnails-01.jpg#xywh=160,0,320,90